# why it shows just one of them in activity? discord js v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i have **this code :**

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM count WHERE default = 'true'`, (err, row) => {
        activities = [
            `${row[0].members} Members`,
            `${row[0].channels} Channels`
        ];
    });
    setInterval(() => {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1) + 1);
        const newActivity = activities[randomIndex];
        client.user.setActivity(`${newActivity}`, { type: 'WATCHING' });
    }, 10000);
```

I checked sql everything is ok with mysql and it shows only one of them (it have to change status every 10 second but it doesn't work)
*and there is no error*

**thank you for your help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it.
yeah it's true JavaScript start at `0` and formula to **get a random element from an array is**: `var item = activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)];`
so i had to remove **this :** `const newActivity = activities[randomIndex];` and make the activities **like this :**

Array(
`${${row[0].members} Members`,
`${${row[0].channels} Channels`
);

***thank you***

Answer (score 0):

Remember that arrays in JavaScript start at `0` and the formula to get a random element from an array is `array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];`

In your case, you are using the formula `activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1) + 1)]`. Therefore, the array will always get index `1`

Comment: hello and thank you, I did like this but this time it shows WATCHING undefined. I checked sql again and I get result from console.log() the sql is ok